# Write an object's speed to an attribute using geometry nodes simulation?

Tags: geometry-nodes, simulation-nodes

I thought what's shown in the image below would work, but I'm having a difficult time because it seems the Evaluated spreadsheet doesn't update consistently.

And if you put this node group on an object with no keyframes at all, but rather as a child to an object which is already animated, then you don't get any output at all?

(Also, I'm only interested in a single speed per object, but for that you apparently need to convert the geometry to an instance, which feels... weird?)

[image]

Comment: @Chris I thought I *was* subtracting my object's old position from the new position, divided by Delta Time. Is that not what I'm doing? To me, it looks like that's what I'm doing. If you can post a working example, then I'll accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

this works, if you don't use the self object, but another object:

[image]

Note: you have to check "relative" to get the current location

result:

constant speed for linear animation, changing speed for bezier

[image]

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to a very helpful Discord, it was pointed out to me that the output Location node had the wrong input. This configuration works:

[image]